# TortoiseSVN commit window freezing (Windows 10)

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

My TortoiseSVN's (v 1.8) commit window freezes every time I try committing changes from the root directory. Interestingly this doesn't happen if I drill down into the specific directory where the modification took place. This problem only happens for only one of my repos that I have checked out (the others seem to be fine). I am using **Windows 10**.

After doing some research, I have tried:

- Disabling icon overlays (even setting the exclude path with `C:\*`
- Setting the icon overlays status cache to 'none'
- Running a cleanup (right click -> TortoiseSVN -> Cleanup)
- Clearing the log caching
- Cleaning the solution from Visual Studio
- Trying to open commit window using `TortoiseProc.exe /command:commit /path:"path\to\your\workingcopy"`

HTTPS is being used and I am not using any SolidWorks files which I discovered to be the cause of a similar issue with a lot of other people.

If anyone has encountered similar issues or has any suggestions, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solving this by upgrading to v 1.9.5 and rechecking out the repo and just copying and replacing the modified files.